# js using encrypt image

Tags: javascript, image

I have a solution to encrypt the image content while storing and transporting:

1. Encode the image content: base64 → AES → base64
2. Get the encoded data by ajax
3. Decode the data to base64 data by `encryptTo.js`
4. Make an Image object by data url, for example:

   ```
        var image = new Image(); 
        image.src="data:image/jpeg,"+imgData.
   ```
5. Display the image object

This solution works on Firefox and Safari. But it's doesn't work on Internet Explorer or Google Chrome.

The reason is that data URL (step 4) is not supported on Internet Explorer or Chrome very well. The image object can not be created.

I searched and found that MHT file format is well supported by Internet Explorer. But it seems like it can only be inserted into the static file.

I thought about using VBScript to call some ActiveX app to solve this problem. But I'm not familiar to VBScript.

I want to get some help to figure out how to do to solve this problem. MHT or VBScript with ActiveX? Which is preferred and easier?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask for the use case here? Why go through this trouble to begin with?

Comment: What's wrong with SSL?

Comment: @deceze  ...given the fact, that once on client side the images can be ripped anyway.

Comment: @youngplayer Can you give us a link to an example (of your code and an image) that works in FF and Safari but not in IE or Chrome? I would be happy to look at it tomorrow. (I'm about to go to sleep right now--already up two hours too late!)

Answer (score 2):

Update: I am providing working code to the OP for loading an image through JavaScript. The example has two images, one with a data URI embedded directly in the HTML, and the other image with a data URI constructed by an Ajax callback after downloading a text file containing base64 image data. Please note that

- Whitespace is officially unsafe / not supported in URLs, so I removed whitespace/linebreaks from the base64 data in the text file ahead of time. You could modify my code to do this in JavaScript by adding the line `base64img = base64img.replace(/\s+/g, '');`
- You should see two images when you view this link: http://www.codelib.net/2013/7-9/example.html
- My example uses some very minified library functions for Ajax, etc., but I am not suggesting that you use them. Your own function should work just as well.
- The result in my example works in recent versions of Opera, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Internet Explorer (including version 8).
- Although you are encrypting and decrypting your data, in principle showing the image works just the same. However, I suggest that you look at the decrypted data to make sure that your decryption algorithm is working properly in all browsers, if you still have problems getting things to work.

The correct way of constructing a data URI is important. Properly formed data URIs are supported by reasonably up-to-date versions of all major browsers right now. It sounds like you are using the proper URI scheme based on your comment, but seeing your code would help others or myself diagnose what is happening.

Are you forming your data URI using binary data or leaving it in base64 encoding? Leaving it in base64 encoding is probably necessary to avoid some browsers trying to interpret the binary data as Unicode character values. Your image `src` should look like the example below, but I only see the `,` and not the preceding `;base64` in your question, which is why I am wondering if you are using a base64-encoded URL which is safer than trying to use binary data (even if it is generated by JavaScript):

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Maybe all you need is to supply the missing `;base64` before the comma and then it should work. Internet Explorer has supported data URIs like this since version 8, with much better support in version 9. Google Chrome definitely supports this type of image.

Note that users can still save the image with no problem (I just tried saving a data image, and even in Internet Explorer 10 it was no different than saving a normal image). Even if you disable right click, people can still open the document inspector or its equivalent, and save the image by inspecting the page's resources. You can draw to a canvas element, but even then a user can still take a screen shot and get a pixel-for-pixel rendering of the image.

Comment: Thanks! I missed base64 in the sample.

Comment: As I said, this solution is ok on firefox and safari. So, it's just a mistake while I post this question. :)

Comment: @youngplayer OK, I thought you had. I just checked all four major browsers with data images and they all work fine.

Comment: how do you check? <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,......"> It does work! but if you use js to create a image object, it won't work

Comment: @youngplayer that's why we need to see what's going on in your code, if you don't mind posting it. (The code that you post should be at least enough to show your process working on Firefox and Safari, but not working on Internet Explorer or Chrome.)  I'm about one minute away from going to sleep now, so I'll check back sometime tomorrow. Good luck!

Comment: var imgData1 = "R0lGODlhFAAUALMAAP//////AP8A//8AAAD//wD/AAAA/wAAALKyspCQkGlpaf///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAsALAAAAAAUABQAAARXcMlJq6Un633n/kcnZUhpZuJ4JGyCWpp3KMq7xDee21yO8CHVL0hyBTGroTBRO+YUCaWPaXtGX8Wq6ko8SHMyaW937OkyNKBT1jKmfKaStgIaX+q69zsCADs="; 
  window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("test1").src="data:image/gif;base64,"+imgData1;
  var imgData=getData2("psd.txt");
 Document.getElementById("test").src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imgData;

Comment: function getData2(dataSource)
   {
    var XMLHttpRequestObject=false;   
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
    XMLHttpRequestObject=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else if(window.ActiveXObject)
   {
    XMLHttpRequestObject=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
    if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
    { 
     XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET",dataSource,false);
     XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');     
     XMLHttpRequestObject.send('');     
     return XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;  
    }
  return "";
   }

Comment: var img = new Image();
 img.src= "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imgData;
 if(img)
  alert(1);
 else
  alert(2); 

var img1 = new Image();
 img1.src= "data:image/gif;base64,"+imgData1;
 if(img1)
  alert(11);
 else
  alert(12);   
 }

Comment: sorry about the above codes a little confused. These just show one difference between local static txt and remote txt by ajax. Ofcourse, the psd.txt is a file that a jpeg file in base64 encoding.

Comment: @youngplayer I was hoping for a working link from you since that is the about the only way to see everything interacting together and find unexpected bugs. I added an example to my answer showing one example of how to successfully load a base64 image with JavaScript in all of the major browsers. I hope that this helps you.

Comment: I've found the reason. After create a image object. when pass img.src to another object, ie8 report that img.src is an invalid pointer....

Comment: It's said that ie8 supported less than 32k base64 encoded file.So it's reasonable to report "invalid pointer" when the file's size is larger than 32k. But I've tried a file about 31k, which got  "invalid pointer" too. I'm puzzeled....

Comment: <html>   
    <body>
    <img id="test" src=""/>
    </body>

  window.onload = function () {
      var imgData = getData2("bbb.txt");
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgData;
      alert(img.src);
      document.getElementById("test").src = img.src;
  }
 </script>
    </html>

Comment: well, I've solved the problem. pass img.href insteadof img.src if is ie8